# How to appropriately assign an object being passed from one View Controller to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a new Obj C programmer so please bear with me.  My data structure is as follows:

> A bill contains a receipt and an array. A receipt contains an array of
>   receiptItems. ReceiptItems contain a string called itemName.

I am passing a custom object of type Receipt created in one view controller to another view controller.  I am doing so through a custom init method.  The code is below:

```
- (id)initWithReceipt:(Receipt *)currentReceipt
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"SplitCheckViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        ReceiptItem *temp1 = (ReceiptItem *)[currentReceipt.receiptItemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(temp1.itemName);
        currentBill.originalReceipt = currentReceipt;
        ReceiptItem *temp2 = (ReceiptItem *)[self.currentBill.originalReceipt.receiptItemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(temp2.itemName);
    }
    return self;
}
```

currentReceipt is being passed through and contains the appropriate data per the first NSLog output.  However, once I try to assign this object to a property in this view controller (currentBill.originalReceipt) I get a blank output for the second NSLog.  I'm sure it is something basic but I am perplexed.

Comment: use delegates to pass value to one vc to anoter vc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to allocate currentBill. Try to print currentBill after the first NSLog.

Comment: Yes - I had forgotten to allocate currentBill.  Additionally, currentBill.originalReceipt was a "weak" property.  I have allocated it and changed its property type to strong and I the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From your title, You want to pass object from first view controller to second view controller. There are so many ways to do so.

1. Use singleton class set value in the first view controller and retrieve the value in second view controller.
2. Store values using keychain, sqllite, core data, plist or any ways you can store.
3. Most commonly using is when you initialise second view controller, give value to second view controller's property, and then show second view controller

   - If want to get value from second view controller in the first view controller, then commonly using is delegate.

I believe there are other ways to do it.